# Python Random Match

Tags: python, random, while-loop, match

How can I modify + add from my code so that it prints both the name of the winner and the winning number?! So let's say William with random number 7 matched with winning number 7. Then I want it to print that "William is the winner and the winning number was 7!". In the other hand, if the winning number was 5 and no one had that matching number, I want it to print out "There is no winner". Thanks in advance!

```
import random
from random import sample
character_count = 5

names = ['John', 'William', 'James', 'George', 'Charles', 'Frank', 'Joseph', 'Henry', 'Robert', 'Thomas', 'Edward',
'Harry', 'Walter', 'Arthur', 'Fred', 'Albert', 'Samuel', 'Clarence', 'Louis', 'David', 'Mary', 'Anna', 'Emma', 'Elizabeth',
'Margaret', 'Minnie', 'Ida', 'Bertha', 'Clara', 'Alice', 'Annie', 'Florence', 'Bessie', 'Grace', 'Ethel', 'Sarah',
'Ella', 'Martha', 'Nellie', 'Mabel']

generate_random_names = (sample(names, k=character_count))

random_number = random.sample(range(1,10), (5))
winning_number = random.sample(range(1,10), (1))

character_status = list(zip(generate_random_names, random_number))

char_one_info = (character_status[0])
char_two_info = (character_status[1])
char_three_info = (character_status[2])
char_four_info = (character_status[3])
char_five_info = (character_status[4])

while True:
    winning_number == char_one_info[1] or winning_number == char_two_info[1] or winning_number == char_three_info[1] or winning_number == char_four_info[1] or winning_number == char_five_info[1]
    print (True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited your code a little to make it more readable and simplified imports.

```
import random
character_count = 5

names = ['John', 'William', 'James', 'George', 'Charles', 'Frank', 'Joseph', 'Henry', 'Robert', 'Thomas', 'Edward’, 'Harry', 'Walter', 'Arthur', 'Fred', 'Albert', 'Samuel', 'Clarence', 'Louis', 'David', 'Mary', 'Anna', 'Emma', 'Elizabeth’, 'Margaret', 'Minnie', 'Ida', 'Bertha', 'Clara', 'Alice', 'Annie', 'Florence', 'Bessie', 'Grace', 'Ethel', 'Sarah’, 'Ella', 'Martha', 'Nellie', 'Mabel']

generate_random_names = random.sample(names, k=character_count)

random_numbers = random.sample(range(1,10), 5)
winning_number = random.randint(1, 10)

character_status = list(zip(generate_random_names, random_numbers))
if winning_number in random_numbers:
    winner = [c for c in character_status if c[1] == winning_number][0]
    print(f"{winner[0]} is the winner and the winner had {winner[1]}!")
else:
    print("Nobody won")
```

Note that if you are running <3.6, change `print(f"{winner[0]} is the winner and the winner had {winner[1]}!”)` to `print(“{name} is the winner and the winner had {num}!”.format(name=winner[0], num=winner[1])`

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if the loop is supposed to continue until a winner is found or not, so I've removed it. I am using a `dict` to store the mapping between numbers and names so I can easily look up if someone has won (the lottery?). You didn't specify a python version, but the code below works with 2.7.

```
import random
character_count = 5

names = ['John', 'William', 'James', 'George', 'Charles', 'Frank', 'Joseph',
         'Henry', 'Robert', 'Thomas', 'Edward', 'Harry', 'Walter', 'Arthur',
         'Fred', 'Albert', 'Samuel', 'Clarence', 'Louis', 'David', 'Mary',
         'Anna', 'Emma', 'Elizabeth', 'Margaret', 'Minnie', 'Ida', 'Bertha',
         'Clara', 'Alice', 'Annie', 'Florence', 'Bessie', 'Grace', 'Ethel',
         'Sarah', 'Ella', 'Martha', 'Nellie',
         'Mabel']

generate_random_names = (random.sample(names, k=character_count))
random_number = random.sample(range(1, 10), 5)
character_status = list(zip(random_number, generate_random_names))
char_info = dict([character_status[i] for i in range(5)])

# You can just use randint here
winning_number = random.randint(1, 10)

while True:
    if winning_number in char_info:
        name = char_info[winning_number]
        print "{0} is the winner and the winning number was {1}!"\
            .format(name, winning_number)
    else:
        print "There is no winner"

    break
```